# How to check all textboxes in a page with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I placed many textboxes on my page and all have the same class `.myClass`.

I want to check if all are filled out or not. How I can find out via jQuery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<strike>You could check that none of them are *not* checked:</strike>

```
if ($('.myClass:checkbox:not(:checked)').length > 0) {
    // Not all checked
}
```

Misread. Check this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TcFBY/) on JsFiddle:

```
$(function() {
    $('input').change(function() {
        var $all = $(':text.myClass');
        var $empty = $all.filter('[value=""]');

        if ($empty.length == 0) {
            $('#out').text('none empty');
        } else if ($all.length == $empty.length) {
            $('#out').text('all empty');
        } else {
            $('#out').text('partial')
        }
    });
});
```

Should give you a hint of a possible approach to a solution.

Comment: please read question carefully i am worried about textbox not checkbox you understand ?

Comment: @4thpage: You've written "check" so often that I've read "checkbox" myself, until I edited your question wording.

Answer (score 3):

```
if ($('input:text.myClass[value=""]').length > 0)
{
    // you have some text boxes which are empty
}
```

Comment: are it is suitable  var q = $(".quan").each(function (index) {
                if ($(this).val() == "") { result == false; }
            });

Comment: If you want to do something in the iteration then go for the `.each()` function.

Comment: The above code will filter the inputs of type text, class myclass and with empty values.

Answer (score 1):

Please see this, hope it helps. Also the code bellow will apply a $.trim() so that inputs filled with a space will validate as empty.

```
$("input.myClass").each(function(){
    if($.trim($(this).val()) == ""){
        // if you reach this then at least one textfield is not filled.
        // so this is where you decide what to do ( for example, assign FALSE to a 'all_textfileds_filled' variable )
    }
});
```

Cheers

Comment: No, I just moved a misplaced parenthesis, cf. [revisions](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/3958806/revisions). You passed `$(this).val() == ""` to `$.trim()` :)